# Question on this thm: Let $R$ be a ring with unity $1$. Then the map $\phi$: $Z$ $\to$ $R$ given by $\phi(n) = n \cdot 1$ is a ring homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> My question: Why does the operation  $n \cdot 1$ move an $n\in \Bbb Z$ to an element in $R$?

It seems that the function just places every element in $\Bbb Z$ into the ring $R$, implying $R \subseteq \Bbb Z$, but there seems to be nothing in the fact that "$R$ is a ring with unity $1$" that would imply this. Where has my reasoning gone wrong? Am I understanding the operation "$n \cdot 1$" incorrectly?

Comment: It means $\phi(n) = n \cdot 1_R$ where $1_R \in R$ is the multiplicative identity of $R$.

Comment: You haven't stated how you are interpreting $n\cdot1,$ so we cannot answer your question. For the record, the correct interpretation is: $$n\cdot1 = \underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n\text{ times}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

The $1$ you talk about is the unity of $R$, so $1\in R$. The notation $n \cdot 1$ means
$$\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{n\text{ times}}$$ so $n \cdot 1 \in R$.

You note that this seems to imply that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq R$, which is almost correct. It is true (up to isomorphism) in the case that the homomorphism is injective. If not then certain elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ will get mapped to the same element in $R$. This is effectively taking a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ so the correct (interesting) conclusion is that we always have that $R$ contains some quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ (up to isomorphism).

Where I say "up to isomorphism", I mean that $R$ doesn't have to contain a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$, but it does contain $\text{Im}(\phi)$ which is isomorphic to a quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$.